# Conv1D layers on 1 dimensional data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I've seen many answers to this exact topic but i still couldn't figure out the solution to my case.

Here is my model:

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_nodes1, hidden_nodes2, hidden_nodes3):
        super().__init__();
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu',input_shape=(8,1));
        self.maxpool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid');
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu');
        self.maxpool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid');
        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu');
        self.flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten();
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_nodes1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu');
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_nodes2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu');
        self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_nodes3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu');
        self.mouth = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear');
    
    def call(self, input):
        layer = self.conv1(input);
        layer = self.maxpool1(layer);
        layer = self.conv2(layer);
        layer = self.maxpool2(layer);
        layer = self.conv3(layer);  
        layer = self.flat(layer);
        layer = self.dense1(layer);
        layer = self.dense2(layer);
        layer = self.dense3(layer);
        return self.mouth(layer);
```

Creating the model this way and passing it to eval_model():
`Model3(128, 512, 256)`

Calling it this way:

```
def eval_model(model, data):
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1);
    print("Evaluating model", model, ",", x_train.shape, ",",y_train.shape);
    model = compile_model(model);
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1);
    test_loss, test_mse, test_mae = model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2);
    angle_mean_abs_error = angle_mean_absolute_error(model, data);
    return test_mse, test_mae, angle_mean_abs_error;
```

Print statement output:
`Evaluating model <NeuralNetwork.Model object at 0x102d2ddf0> , (72000, 8, 1) , (72000,)`

Dataset shapes:

- x_train: (72000, 8) - Train features
- y_train: (72000,) - Train labels
- x_test: (72000, 8) - Test features
- y_test: (72000,) - Test labels

A sample from the data set looks like this..
`[-50.68016269902751,-123.5931837945475,-135.6931812031858,-52.7689061034506,56.32868399246948,119.0166180595376,137.2685783599205,54.98762026269321,1]`

where the first 8 numbers are features and the last one is the label.

The Conv1D layer requires an input shape with 3 dimensions (right?), so what I did was reshaping the x_train tensor from (72000,8) to (72000, 1, 8) with this line: `x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=1)`, but it's throwing this error: `Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node model3/max_pooling1d/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 1, 1]](model3/max_pooling1d/ExpandDims)' with input shapes: [32,1,1,32].` which I have no idea what it means.

Also, if I remove the MaxPooling layers this classic error: `Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)` is thrown.

I would appreciate some clarifications about this..

Comment: try `x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)` and `x_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=-1)` and change input_shape to `(8, 1)` and after your last `Conv1D` layer, add a `Flatten` layer.

Comment: Okay, with `x_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=-1)` you mean `x_test = np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=-1)` (or the labels)? I've also changed the input_shape to (8,1) in the first conv1D layer and added a Flatten layer after the third conv1D layer. Here's what it got thrown: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)`.

Comment: Always use `x` for features and `y` for your labels.....make sure `x_train` (Train features) with the shape `(72000, 8)` has the shape `(72000, 8, 1)` and make sure that is the same for `x_test` (Test features)

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, I think I fixed it in the post now. Yes, the x_train has the shape `(72000, 8, 1)`. The error is occurring in the fitting stage so I don't know if changing the x_test will have any effect.

Comment: I am not sure I understand...what exactly is your error now?

Comment: Right now, with all the changes you've mentioned, and the shape of x_train being `(72000, 8, 1)` the error being thrown is this `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)`.

Comment: Okay, just added the changes, you can now see how I call the model.fit. The data parameter is how im receiving the data, you can assume x_train is data.x_train

Comment: Okay, I've added that aswell.

Comment: Please show how you create your model object and are you sure your error is not coming after `model.fit` when you call `model.evaluate` on your test data?

Comment: Wow, it is..omg I can't believe im this stupid..Im sorry you were right all along ahah. The error was really being throwned in the evaluate function, just changed the shape of x_test and it works! Im sorry for wasting your time, thank you anyways man!

Comment: No problem. Have fun ;)